# Auto-increment a field within each category?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have an auto-increment field called sequence.  I only want it to increment by 1 within the topic this model is in.   Usually the most would ever be is about 10.  Then resets for a new topic. I would like this to be done in a save override method:

```
class Video(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('video.VideoTopic')
    sequence = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get last value of sequence and increment by 1
        top = Video.objects.order_by('-sequence')[0]
        self.sequence = top.sequence + 1
        super(Video, self).save()
```

Problem with my code here is that "top" in the save method will only get the video with the highest numbered sequence.

How do I get the topic of the video being saved from which to filter my query properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it from `self.topic`:

```
top = Video.objects.filter(topic=self.topic).order_by('-sequence')[0]
```

You can also use [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) instead of sorting and taking `[0]` out of the queryset:

```
top = Video.objects.filter(topic=self.topic).latest('sequence')
```

In this case `latest()` would get the single `Video` model instance that has the maximum `sequence` value for the particular topic.

See also: [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Comment: Super, thanks!  I ended up with:

    sequence_number = 1

        top = Video.objects.filter(topic=self.topic).latest('sequence')

        if top.sequence:

            sequence_number = top.sequence + 1

        self.sequence = sequence_number

        super(Video, self).save()